# New to .net core, opened a .net core .sln file but all libraries(using) faded

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I just downloaded this https://github.com/moemura/AdminLTE.Core to play with .net core.

But when I opened it with Visual Studio 2017. I'm getting this:
[image]

So it looks like I need to import AspNetCore, but where to get those files? I'd assume the .sln should work out of the box?

Comment: Never mind, I think I need to update Visual Studio latest and download .net core and target the .sln

Comment: You can try downloading it from Nuget Package Manager.
Tools->NuGet package manager->Manage NuGet Packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you select **asp.net core** when you install VS 2017? Open Visual studio installer and check it first. 
[image]

If you have installed it.I think you need to **update your VS IDE**.You can easily update it by clicking small flag icon with yellow button.Check below Image.
[image]